# Unable to hide elements inside a form in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide and element inside a form but it's not working.
here's my code:

```
<style>
    .hide {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="submit" id="show" value="Show" />
    <input type="submit" value="Hide" id="hide"  />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* save the 2 nodes to variables */
    var button = document.getElementById("show"),
     target = document.getElementById("hide");
    /* define what we want to do in a function */
    function hide(){
        target.setAttribute("class","hide");
    }
    /* add the CSS class when the button is clicked */
    button.addEventListener("click", hide, false);

</script>
</body>
```

- But it works if I take it out of the form container. Please explain...

Comment: Please avoid using submit when you are not submitting. Use button rather.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the code isn't working, is because you're using `submit` buttons.
They submit the form, making the page reload, preventing your JavaScript from doing it's thing.

Replace:

```
<input type="submit" id="show" value="Show" />
<input type="submit" value="Hide" id="hide"  />
```

With:

```
<input type="button" id="show" value="Show" />
<input type="button" value="Hide" id="hide"  />
```

**[Working example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/94Pej/)**

When you click the "Show" button, it hides the "hide" button, just as the code says it should.

Answer (score 2):

I think it actually works. You can [check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x42ez/) (`the code is the same`)

Before submission hide button gets hidden.

Maybe your problem is you don't realize that if you put buttons inside the form you're actually sending. When you press button it sets target class to hide and submit the form, thus rerendering (without the hide class).